# Difference Between True and true

Tags: python

I was practising a python related problem at Hackerrank. I am a total newbie to python. The Problem was to simply write a function, which checks if a year is leap year or not according to the Gregorian calendar.

I looked in the discussions tab, where I found out the answer, I decided to not to copy up the code and instead I wrote the code after understanding it.

So I wrote it this way:

```
if year%4 == 0 and (year%100 != 0 or year%400 == 0):
    leap = true;
```

When I ran the tests, It ended up with two failed tests and two timed out tests. So I checked the solution in the discussions tab again and changed my code to:

```
if year%4 == 0 and (year%100 != 0 or year%400 == 0):
    leap = True
```

When I ran this code, all my test cases passed, without any errors.

Does python have only 'True' and not 'true'?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Python only has `True`. Did you check the Python documentation? The [standard types section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) would have answered this very quickly.

Comment: @Martijn true, from python 2.3, before only 1 and 0

Comment: @AriGold: 2.3 is now ancient history. HackerRank certainly doesn't support it.

Comment: now is relative but yeah

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Okay, Thank you I should have looked up the documentation, also thank you for sending me the link to it.

Comment: `True` is a builtin boolean object in Python.  "true" would be an ordinary user-defined variable. Since "true" was not previously assigned, it will throw an error.

Comment: `True` is a valid built-in, `true` raises `NameError: name 'true' is not defined` (unless, of course, you assign some value to it previously).

Comment: you can assign `true = True` and your code could run. But `True` is a boolean constant and python is case sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True is capitalised because Python built in constants are capitalised: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html

"true" would create an error, as the program will be looking for a non-existant variable called true.

Comment: Could do `true = True` though. Or for even more fun: `true = False; false = True` :-)

Comment: Thanks @dahui for explaining it, python keeps getting interesting for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `True` is the keyword and `true` is not. The flag is case sensitive. It is always `True` and `False`, not `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Truth and False are keywords meaning true and false . Just like the keyword for null is None . Truth is the literal truth value

Answer (score -1):

Python is case sensitive and strongly typed.

'true' is not the same as 'TRUE'

[Graphic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU2H9.png)